# Pick the correct shape for these patterns

Tags: pattern

Does anyone know the correct shape that corresponds to the following patterns of shapes for each image and explain why?

Part A
[image: Part A]

Part B
[image: Part B]

Comment: Sorry but where is the source?

Comment: Please attribute the source, or it will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First is E since for the top bar 3 the third shape is a combination of previous two bars and the bottom dots alternate 2,4,2,4

> Second is E and the logic is that the shapes surrounding the rotation symbol rotate 45 degrees anticlockwise, and change to another shape and white becomes black and vice versa. From left to right that is.

Comment: pB, Looks like it is flipped in 3 dimensions on a 45 degree 2d axis and the shapes changed?